# C++: How to change expression template to handle infinite amount of sums?

Tags: c++, templates, expression

I wrote an expression template to sum up to three vectors together. However, as you can see in my code, this doesn't scale very well because for every additional sum operand I have to add another nested template expression. Is there a way to refactor this code to handle a (theoretically) infinite amount of additions?

```
template<class A>
struct Expr {
    operator const A&() const {
        return *static_cast<const A*>(this);
    }
};

template<class A, class B>
class Add : public Expr<Add<A,B>> {
private:
    const A &a_;
    const B &b_;
public:
    Add(const A &a, const B &b) : a_(a), b_(b) { }

    double operator[] (int i) const {
        return a_[i] + b_[i];
    }
};

class Vector : public Expr<Vector> {
private:
    double *data_;
    int n_;
public:
    Vector(int n, double w = 0.0) : n_(n) {
        data_ = new double[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            data_[i] = w;
        }
    }

    double operator[] (int i) const {
        return data_[i];
    }

    friend Expr<Add<Vector, Vector>> operator+(Vector &a, Vector &b) {
        return Add<Vector, Vector>(a, b);
    }

    friend Expr<Add<Add<Vector, Vector>, Vector>> operator+(const Add<Vector, Vector> &add, const Vector &b) {
        return Add<Add<Vector, Vector>, Vector>(add, b);
    }

    template<class A>
    void operator= (const Expr<A> &a) {
        const A &a_(a);
        for(int i = 0; i < n_; ++i) {
            data_[i] = a_[i];
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr int size = 5;
    Vector a(size, 1.0), b(size, 2.0), c(size);
    c = a + b + a;

    return 0;
}
```

This was working for me:

```
class Vector : public Expr<Vector> {
private:
    double *data_;
    int n_;
public:
    Vector(int n, double w = 0.0) : n_(n) {
        data_ = new double[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            data_[i] = w;
        }
    }

    double operator[] (int i) const {
        return data_[i];
    }

    template<class A, class B>
    friend Add<A, B> operator+(const Expr<A> &a, const Expr<B> &b) {
        return Add<A, B>(a, b);
    }

    template<class A>
    void operator= (const Expr<A> &a) {
        const A &a_(a);
        for(int i = 0; i < n_; ++i) {
            data_[i] = a_[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Expr` class here? If `operator+` would return a new `Vector` this would be a non-issue.

Comment: This is not that safe, as you don't know if the vectors have equal length.... But just to be clear: it seems you want lazy evaluation?

Comment: @super - So your suggestion is to not use expression templates at all.

Comment: @binaryBigInt - If you want a *family* of very similiar `operator+` functions, then that means *template*.

Comment: I think I found a solution. What do you think?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's not so much a suggestion as an attempt to clarify what OP wants. I can imagine some reasons why OP wants the `Expr` class, but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Your update should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no template wizard (and I'm not up-to-date with the latest possibilities), but you can at least make a function that added a variadic amount of vectors, using something like described in the code below.

You could then buildup you expressiontree like you did before and call this function in you evaluation (operator=) function.

edit: updated the code, based on [this solution (credits there)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087034)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T, typename...Args>
auto AddVector_impl(Vec<Args> const & ... vecs){
    auto its = std::tuple(cbegin(vecs)...);

    auto add_inc = [](auto&... iters){
        return ((*iters++) + ... );
    };
    auto end_check = [&](auto&...iters){
        return ((iters != cend(vecs)) && ...);
    };
    Vec<T> res;
    for(auto it = back_inserter(res); apply(end_check,its);){
        *it++ = apply(add_inc,its);
    }
    return res;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Vec<T> AddVector(Vec<T> const& vt, Vec<Args> const&...  vargs){
    return AddVector_impl<T>(vt,vargs...);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr auto size = 5;
    Vec<double> a(size, 1.0), b(size, 2.0);
    auto c = AddVector(a, b, a);

    for(auto const& el : c){
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: And of course you should use SFINAE or concepts