# Getting UB in my variadic template summing a variable number of vectors element-wise

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to make a function `AddVector` that adds a (variable) number of vectors element wise. I think I got it, but as I get the wrong output, I clearly don't. I'm adding three vectors of doubles, each sized 5, containing 1+2+1, thus I expect

```
4 4 4 4 4
```

I get

```
1.36234e-316 2.0326e-316 4 4 4
```

Which is clearly wrong (maybe uninitialized mem?)

I used CppInsights to look at the translated code, but that also seemed OK. What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
auto SumAndIncVcIt(T& t) {
    return *t++;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto SumAndIncVcIt(T& t, Args&... args) {
    return *t++ + SumAndIncVcIt(args...);
}

#include <tuple>
template<typename... Args>
auto VcBegins(Args... args){
    return std::make_tuple(cbegin(args)...);
}

template<typename T, size_t... Is>
auto SumAndIncVcIts_impl(T& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return SumAndIncVcIt(std::get<Is>(t)...);
}

template<class Tuple>
auto SumAndIncVcIts(Tuple& t) {
    return SumAndIncVcIts_impl(t,
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>{}>{}
    );
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Vec<T> AddVector(Vec<T> const& vt, Vec<Args> const&...  vargs){
    auto vret = Vec<T>(size(vt));
    auto vcIts = VcBegins(vt, vargs...);
    auto retIt = begin(vret);
    while(retIt != end(vret)){
        *retIt++ = SumAndIncVcIts(vcIts);
    }
    return vret;
}

#include<iostream>

int main() {
    constexpr auto size = 5;
    Vec<double> a(size, 1.0), b(size, 2.0);
    auto c = AddVector(a, b, a);

    for(auto const& el : c){
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
}
```

p.s. yes, I should use SFINEA or concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Not sure where lies your problem yet,</s> You found it yourself :)  ... But this is how I would implement it with C++17 and sizes:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T, typename...Args>
Vec<T> AddVector_impl(Vec<Args> const & ... vecs){
    auto sizes = {vecs.size()...};
    auto new_size = *std::min_element(sizes.begin(),sizes.end());

    Vec<T> res(new_size);

    for(std::size_t i=0;i<new_size;++i){
        res[i]=(vecs[i]+...);
    }
    return res;
}

// Ensures at least one vector, also sets its return type.
template<typename T, typename... Args>
Vec<T> AddVector(Vec<T> const& vt, Vec<Args> const&...  vargs){
    return AddVector_impl<T>(vt,vargs...);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr auto size = 5;
    Vec<double> a(size, 1.0), b(size, 2.0);
    auto c = AddVector(a, b, a);

    for(auto const& el : c){
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
}
```

[Live Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c4TMT8)

Output:

```
4 4 4 4 4
```

### Iterator-only solution

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<T>;


template<typename T, typename...Args>
Vec<T> AddVector_impl(Vec<Args> const & ... vecs){
    auto its = std::tuple(vecs.cbegin()...);

    auto add_inc = [](auto&... iters){
        return ((*iters++) + ... );
    };
    auto end_check = [&](auto&...iters){
        return ((iters!=vecs.cend()) && ...);
    };
    Vec<T> res;
    auto it = std::back_insert_iterator(res);
    while(std::apply(end_check,its)){
        *it++=std::apply(add_inc,its);
    }
    return res;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Vec<T> AddVector(Vec<T> const& vt, Vec<Args> const&...  vargs){
    return AddVector_impl<T>(vt,vargs...);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    constexpr auto size = 5;
    Vec<double> a(size, 1.0), b(size, 2.0);
    auto c = AddVector(a, b, a);

    for(auto const& el : c){
        std::cout << el << " ";
    }
}
```

[Live Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ej5Mv).

Comment: Thanks. I found my error. I'm passing by value in `VcBegins`... invalid iterators. Anyhow, I will look into your solution. I wanted to use iterators, making an STL like algorithm.

Comment: @JHBonarius Alright, yea, iterators make this rather complicated. But you still use `size` function, that does not work with iterators.

Comment: true. But if the interface was `AddVector(cbegin(v1), cend(v1), cbegin(v2), cbegin(v3), ...)` i could use `std::distance`. There will be a big problem is the vectors don't have equal length though... I really appreciate your answer bytheway ;) Maybe I should post this on CodeReview

Comment: p.s., what's the reason for `+0`? It will fail for any type `T` that doesn't have an operator+ overload that takes an `int`.

Comment: @JHBonarius I posted a solution only with using iterators, I reused your tuple idea :)

Comment: @JHBonarius Sorry, that was a leftover before I noticed that you enforce at least one vector in the addition, you can remove it.

Comment: `std::apply` usage is little bit quirky, you have to use a lambda because due to limitations of the language, template functions cannot be passed around as parameters (and both of them would be templated), but lambda objects with templated `operator()` can thankfully. Other than that it is a handy way how to avoid the ugly index sequence stuff with tuples.

Comment: I was thinking... checking all the `cend`s every iteration really slows down the iterator version. Plus you can't `reserve` upfront, so keep resizing upon growth... still needs some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

found it myself...

```
template<typename... Args>
auto VcBegins(Args... args){
    return std::make_tuple(cbegin(args)...);
}
```

passes by value, thus the vectors are copied and I get back invalid iterators

It should of course be

```
template<typename... Args>
auto VcBegins(Args const&... args){
    return std::make_tuple(cbegin(args)...);
}
```